# How to implement method to launch App Gallery in HamonyOS application?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am working on an open-source library for HarmonyOS app development which is used to prompt app users for rating the app on App Gallery. For that, I need to implement a method to launch the app gallery whenever the user agrees to give feedback. For Android, the same functionality is achieved through the following code

```
public void tryCollectingFeedback(@NonNull final Activity currentActivity, String packageName) {
        String GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_URI_PREFIX = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_URI_PREFIX + packageName);
            currentActivity.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri));

        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
        }
    }
```

How do I do this in HarmonyOS ?

Answer (score 0):

HarmonyOS API6 supports this. You can use the simulator to test it.

The following are how to test with API6 and sample code:

```
public void tryCollectingFeedback( String packageName) {
    String GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_URI_PREFIX = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(GOOGLE_PLAY_STORE_URI_PREFIX + packageName);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Operation op = new Intent.OperationBuilder()
            .withAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW_DATA)
            .withUri(uri)
            .build();
    intent.setOperation(op);
    startAbility(intent);
}
```

Currently, API 6 can run only on a phone simulator.

Use the DevEco Studio project creation wizard to create a phone project. The API is API 5. If you want to use API 6, you can modify the project as follows:

1. Create a project according to the operation guide for [creating and configuring a project](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/create_new_project-0000001053342414#section17283172032910).
2. Open the `build.gradle` file of the project and the `build.gradle` file of the module, and change the API versions supported by the project. Change the values of `compileSdkVersion` and `compatibleSdkVersion` to **6**.

```
ohos {
    compileSdkVersion 6
    defaultConfig {
        compatibleSdkVersion 6
    }
}
```

3. The ROM version of the current real device does not support API 6. Choose [Use Remote Emulator to run applications](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/run_simulator-0000001053303709#section1379810553263) and select Mate30.

[image]